I have latest Ubuntu 24.04 version, how to solve acpi errors if I have updated bios software
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [ 58.PCIO.SATO.PRTO. GTF

This question is similar to: ACPI error on every boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
